# Bootstrap 4: Keep a card vertically and horizontally centered but not spill offscreen

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a single page that only contains a vertically and horizontally centered card. The card contains a form and some text inside. The user will submit the form and get a list back. Sometimes the list will be long and the card will be cut off at the top with no way to scroll. Is there anyway to have it hit the top and not spill over? I've tried using padding-top but I don't want the width to effect the percent and a fixed value is no good for different screen sizes.

CSS

```
    html,
    body {
        height: 100%;
    }

    .container,
    .row.justify-content-center.align-items-center {
        height: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
    }
```

Full Example: http://jsbin.com/madigarixu/edit?html,css,output

Comment: what do you mean not spill offscreen? it scrolls for me.

Comment: It does scroll but the form is cut off at the top and you can't scroll up to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `min-height` instead. Also the fixed top navbar requires body padding. Use calc to subtract this from the min-height and the card will be perfectly centered...

```
body {
    padding-top:50px;
}

.container,
.row.justify-content-center.align-items-center {
    min-height: calc(100vh - 50px);
}
```

http://codeply.com/go/pdqcX2t51x

Comment: Thank you! I changed 50px to 57px and it works exactly as I need it.

Answer (score 1):

**You should try this**

```
    html,
    body {
        height: 100%;
    }

    .container,
    .row.justify-content-center.align-items-center {
        height: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
    }
  .justify-content-center {
    min-height:auto !important;
    height:auto !important;
  }
```

[jsfiddle link update your code](https://jsfiddle.net/8zgu2ypu/)

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted! It works on jsfiddle but when I add it to my code it doesn't. Did you change anything else?

Comment: Oh I see, it doesn't keep it centered horizontally and vertically when there's no extra text.

Comment: Please check css conflict some whare